How to pass array parameters to a Postgres query?
I am very new to PostgreSQL and struggling to work with arrays.
I have a table bookIds like this:



book_id
location_id
checked_out_version




12
1
10


15
1
12



From Java code, I am passing arrays of checked out versions, location ids and book ids to a query, and the query needs to:
UPDATE bookIds SET checked_out_version = (values in the array?)
WHERE location_id = ANY (:locationIDS)
AND book_id = ANY (:bookIDS)

I keep getting errors that Postgres does not support updating a col with an array using the SET clause in a UPDATE statement.
I have also tried looping but, obviously, it sets the checked out version to the latest in the array.
Example:
If I pass the following arrays:
bookIds [12,15]
LocationIDS [1,1]
checkedOutVersions [11, 20]
The table needs to be updated to look like



book_id
location_id
checked_out_version




12
1
11


15
1
20



This is the loop I tried:
DO $$
DECLARE
   i integer;
BEGIN
   FOREACH i IN ARRAY :checkedOutVersions::integer[] LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', i;
      UPDATE bookIds SET checked_out_version = i
      WHERE location_id = ANY (:locationIDs::bigint[])
      AND book_id = ANY (:bookIDs::integer[]);
    END LOOP;
END $$;

How to do this properly?

You don't a need a loop in a PL/pgSQL block, so no DO command either.
Use a plain UPDATE statement and unnest your arrays in lockstep with unnest() as set-returning function:
UPDATE bookids b
SET    checked_out_version = t.ver
FROM   unnest('{12,15}'::int[]   -- :bookIDs
            , '{1,1}'::bigint[]  -- :locationIDs
            , '{11,20}'::int[]   -- :checkedOutVersions
       ) AS t(book_id, loc_id, ver)
WHERE  b.location_id = t.loc_id
AND    b.book_id = t.book_id;
AND    checked_out_version IS DISTINCT FROM t.ver  -- avoid empty updates
;

(Ideas with location_id = ANY (:locationIDs::bigint[]) etc. would result in a Cartesian product of elements from combined arrays. Expensive nonsense.)
See:

Unnest multiple arrays in parallel

I added the filter AND checked_out_version IS DISTINCT FROM t.ver to avoid empty updates. See:

How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?

Note the syntax for Postgres array literals:

Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function

Maybe as prepared statement? Prepare:
PREPARE upd1(int[], bigint[], int[]) AS
UPDATE bookids b
SET    checked_out_version = t.ver
FROM   unnest($1, $2, $3) AS t(book_id, loc_id, ver)
WHERE  b.location_id = t.loc_id
AND    b.book_id = t.book_id
AND    checked_out_version IS DISTINCT FROM t.ver;

Execute:
EXECUTE upd1('{12,15}', '{1,1}', '{11,20}');

fiddle
No explicit type casts needed in the call, since parameter types have been declared in PREPARE. Also implicitly safe against SQL injection (which can be a problem with simple interpolation / concatenation).  Don't know much about JDBC, but every major programming language has libraries to handle prepared statements.
Aside: Use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers to make your life with Postgres easier. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?

